Autopilot - Intune: Get Hardware-Hashes to Backup
How can I backup devices from Autopilot before deletion?
Once deleted, I would like to be able to undo deletes by re-adding devices.
For this, I need the hardware-hash
But https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/windowsAutopilotDeviceIdentities does not list the 4000byte hardware hash.
Background: As a school, when leaving, students can take their devices with them. Often, they need to attach to a different school's tenant - so the record has to be deleted from out Autopilot first.
To avoid false deletes, I would like to keep a backup, because for us it is only possible to add devices with the hardware-hash.
Extracting from running devices is no option (too complicated).
Does Autopilot not expose the stored HW-Hash anywhere, as it does with the other properties of the devices?
